# Finding a last minute hostel in Ko Phi Phi Don (some Hostels don't have websites)

Tags: thailand, hostels, phi-phi

The situation I face is the following. I would like to spend a night in a cheap hostel in Thailand, Ko Phi Phi Don. The thing is that I'm a little late, every hostel is booked and unavailable. Now I've heard that many hostel do not have a website.

Thus, my question, is it easy to find a sleeping place over there in Ko Phi Phi Don without arranging a hostel through internet?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on when you are going.  Koh Phi Phi doesn't have lots of accommodation and during peak season everything will likely be full.  And unfortunately, if there is no room at the inn, it means arranging a boat ride off the island to search elsewhere.

Now a days, most lodging establishments in Thailand have a website or Facebook page.  So if you are not find anything I might consider either a daytrip or another destination.